# Wankel Engines - Port Tuning

Tags: engine, engine-theory, wankel-engine, porting

## Port Tuning Wankel Engines

In many ways, a wankel engine is like a two-stroke engine.  You can open up the ports to change the timing regarding exhaust and intake.

I've ground many an intake, exhaust and transfer port.  In some cases, high performance pistons would come with stencils to place on the cylinder wall to grind the ports the way the piston manufacturer recommended for peak power at higher RPM's.

It seems to me that wankel engines would have the same type of tunability.

## My Questions:

***Can you port tune a wankel engine?***

Comment: Warning: lots of info about port tuning is secretly held. Take everything online with a grain of salt. I personally know some of the fastest rotary drag racers in the world and no one will talk. No one.

Comment: yeah, that's pretty much SoP in the two stroke world too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely.

Can you port tune a Mazda 13B on your kitchen table with a dremel tool?  Yes.  I've done it.  Better said, I *tried* it.

Can you expect the apex seals to last any time at all using "free" instructions from the internet?  Not a chance.

I'm sure there's plenty to be gained, but I doubt nearly as much as an Otto cycle due to the speed and efficiency of uncovering a port rather than opening a valve.